# How can I compress resource with gzip in Shopify?

Tags: javascript, css, optimization, shopify

I am just trying to optimize my shopify website and it is only 71 on google speed insight. I optimized almost all images, but there are still such errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE8ca.png)

Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those uncompressed assets appear to be served by a third-party app (delivery-date-range.herokuapp.com). You would have to talk to the developer of that app and ask them to serve gzipped storefront assets.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :-)